# install from .tar.gz

Tags: software-installation, tar

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64-bit. I know there are a lot of topics on ".tar.gz" but it didn't answer my questions and/or I didn't undetstand the answers.

I am trying to install from a .tar.gz file and I am having difficulties. The file is from http://popcorn-time.se/
I download it to my home directory and extract it to mentioned directory, there are 3 files in the folder and I don't know what to do with these (usually there is a readme file). Double-clicking them doesn't do anything.

What to do? I would to prefer to solve this within the GUI and avoid the terminal, if possible.

As requested by Xen2050; these is the content of the .tar file:

```
@fz-System-Product-Name:~/Popcorn-Time-linux64$ ls -la
total 103176

drwxrwxr-x  2 fz fz     4096 jan 22 12:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 33 fz fz     4096 jan 22 12:42 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 fz fz  2395800 apr 28  2014 libffmpegsumo.so
-rwxrwxrwx  1 fz fz  4031601 apr 28  2014 nw.pak
-rwxrwxrwx  1 fz fz 99207331 apr 28  2014 Popcorn-Time
```

Comment: Looks like binaries. Try double clicking that `Popcorn-Time` file.

Comment: @karel when I voted, the question was roughly "how do I install popcorn time from this .tar.gz file?" The details were added later.

Comment: The question is not duplicate. old one is for popcorntime.io which is down, but new one is for currently working version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually those types of files are just "extract and run", but if it's not a GUI program, you may *have* to use a terminal and see what the files are, maybe run them there.

And it's almost always preferable to install programs from a [default repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal), or a PPA, if it's available there. `apt-get` or `aptitude` or `synaptic` are excellent ways to install programs available from the repositories.

But, for this .tar.gz, it may only run in a terminal, or may be giving an error message that double-clicking on it isn't revealing.

1. open a terminal
2. cd to the extracted files
3. type `ls -la` and paste the results into your Q, we're looking for which one is executable (has an `x` in the permissions)

After seeing the files, all those files are executable apparently, that's a little different. Can try executing the Popcorn-Time one with `./Popcorn-Time` (have to type a `./` first, or the shell looks in your path for a filename to run, ignoring the current dir).

I did a [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu%20how%20to%20install%20popcorn%20time) and found some promising hits:

- http://lintut.com/run-popcorn-time-on-linux/ - Has info about your error from the comments, this might be your fix:

  If you see Error missing libudev.so.0 enter following command in terminal:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
  ```
- [Install Popcorn Time In Ubuntu Or Debian Via PPA Repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-popcorn-time-in-ubuntu-or.html) - If the above link didn't work, you could do this. In a terminal, run:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install popcorn-time
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how that is an answer to my question. I have downloaded a file that is supposed to work with Ubuntu. I extract it and there are 3 files I don't know what to do with. Is the answer that I shouldn't bother with the .tar file?

The other topic you referred to doesn't mean anything to me - the answers are all over the place; someone is suggesting to compile your own. I want to install from the file I got from the site. It's not just about installing Popcorn, it's mostly about handling a type of file in Ubuntu; .tar.gz.

Comment: Actually, it is quite the opposite. I don't want someone to just tell me what to type, I want to know what I am typing; something ALL instructions on this site lacks. For example: what if I didnt know what ls or cd did (I do)...

Comment: Definitely read the `man` page for any commands you're interested in, as in `man ls` or `man apt-get` (fyi, `apt-get` or `aptitude` or `synaptic` are excellent ways to install programs available from the repositories.  And all those files are executable apparently, that's a little different. Can try executing the Popcorn-Time one with `./Popcorn-Time` (have to type a `./` first, or the shell looks in your path for a filename to run, ignoring the current dir)

Comment: ./Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @FuriousUser that's an onion in the ointment... updated with some other instructions from the web, and using a PPA & apt

Comment: It failed on the last command.



download failed

Popcorn Time is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package popcorn-time (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 popcorn-time
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: That shouldn't happen... even after the missing lib fix " `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0` "?

Comment: I rebooted and then it straightened itself out. So your instructions worked excellent it seems. Thank you, Xen2050!

Comment: Installing via PPA doesn't work anymore as of August 31, 2015

Comment: @Smac89 there's probably an updated answer in the "marked as duplicate of" question above. Or tried the "[ubuntu how to install popcorn time](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu%20how%20to%20install%20popcorn%20time)" duckduckgo web search I linked to?